# Haskell creating a counter with a single input

Tags: list, haskell, recursion

I am a beginner and I want to define a function which shows how many elements are in one list. I already created this :

```
elementsl n []     = n
elementsl n (_:xs) = elementsl (n+1) xs
```

But I need to give two inputs: `0` and a list.
how can I give only the list as a single input and still have a counter in my function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Very simple, define a new function, and define the 'helper' function in a `where` block:

```
elements ls = helper 0 ls --`helper' is your previous function, defined below:
    where helper n []     = n
          helper n (_:xs) = helper (1+n) xs
```

This will prevent `helper` from being used elsewhere, but allows you to write your function in this way.

However, you could avoid this tail-recursion entirely, and just write:

```
elements []     = 0
elements (_:xs) = 1 + elements xs
```

and therefore avoid the need for two arguments. This second style is generally considered more idiomatic haskell.

Comment: I'm unsure with the last sentence, though. The tail recursive version (with a proper strictness fix, or praying the the optimizer fixes it) runs in constant space (provided numbers are of a standard type), while the non tail recursive one uses linear memory. I'd use the first version.